# How to use aioredis with discord.py?

Tags: python, redis, discord.py, aioredis

How to use [aioredis](https://github.com/aio-libs/aioredis) and [discord.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py)?

The problem is that I don't know how to use `discord.ext.commands` with [aioredis.create_redis_pool](https://github.com/aio-libs/aioredis#usage-example).

I'm starting discord bot via

```
from discord.ext import commands

@bot.command("get_count")
async def get_count(ctx):
    count = get_reactions_count()
    # I need to somehow define async redis connection and use it here for example
    await ctx.send("some text")

bot = commands.Bot()
bot.run(config.TOKEN)
```

But how can I define redis client in this case?

PS I know that we can do like this, but is this an optimal solution?

```
@bot.command("get_count")
async def get_count(ctx):
    redis = await aioredis.create_redis_pool(
        'redis://localhost')
    count = get_reactions_count()
    # and use redis connection here
    await ctx.send("some text")
```

Comment: What's difficult about it? I really don't understand what's the issue here. Simply put the code there and that's it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you need somehow to start redis event loop and connect it to discord.py's...

Comment: Also I don't want to redefine redis connection on every request, so I can't "just" put redis connection into "get_count" or can I?

Comment: You can have a bot var, a "global" connection, also there's no need to "connect the event loop", they can have their separate one

Comment: Can you plz show how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep a connection alive you can simply have it as a so called "bot var".

```py
bot.my_variable = 'whatever'
```

You can do the same with the pool, there are two ways:

1.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    bot.pool = await aioredis.create_redis_pool(...)
```

2. 

```py
bot.pool = bot.loop.run_until_complete(aioredit.create_redis_pool(...))
```

To use it simply `bot.pool.some_method`

The second way is the preferred one, the `on_ready` event can be called multiple times.

You also wanted to "connect" the redis event loop with the bot's loop, from the docs I can see that `aioredis.create_redis_pool` takes `loop` as an optional parameter.

```py
await aioredis.create_redis_pool(..., loop=bot.loop)
```